# Exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying a really simple OpenCV example in Python, which completely fails to work for me:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img1 = plt.imread('../data/input/frame000013.png')
    img2 = plt.imread('../data/input/frame000014.png')
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
    print(sift)
    kp = sift.detect(img1_gray, None)
    print(kp)
```

If I try to run it with PyCharm, I get the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

If I try to execute it through the terminal, it just does not seem to get past `kp = sift.detect(img1_gray, None)` line and does not really get to second `print` statement, without providing any error notification whatsoever.

I use: Windows 10, Python 3.8, `opencv-python`&`opencv-contrib-python` 4.4.0.44.

Comment: Mixing libraries like that is never a good idea...

Comment: cv2.SIFT don't exist ..., for OpenCV 4.4.0.44 , syntax is sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html), it should be `SIFT_create()`.

```py
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
print(sift)
kp = sift.detect(img1_gray, None)
```

But, why are you reading images with `plt.imread`?

The reason I'm asking, you are converting to the gray-scale using `BGR2GRAY`. But `plt.imread` returns image as `RGB` format. Therefore, if you are going to use `plt.imread`:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[..., :3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]).astype(np.uint8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img1 = plt.imread('../data/input/frame000013.png')
    img2 = plt.imread('../data/input/frame000014.png')
    img1_gray = rgb2gray(img1)
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    print(sift)
    kp = sift.detect(img1_gray, None)
    print(kp)
```

or if you choose `cv2.imread`:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img1 = cv2.imread('../data/input/frame000013.png')
    img2 = cv2.imread('../data/input/frame000014.png')
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    print(sift)
    kp = sift.detect(img1_gray, None)
    print(kp)
```